# Strange behavior with module.exports and async in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, async-await, node-modules

Here's a very strange issue that has me puzzled. After creating a React app with create-react-app, I added these two files:

**TestMod.js**

```
const TestMod = {
  doSomething() {
  }
};

module.exports = TestMod;
```

**Test.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TestMod from './TestMod';

export default class Test extends Component {  
  render() {
    TestMod.doSomething();
    return <div>Testing</div>;
  }
}
```

I included the `Test` component inside `App`, run `npm start`, and everything worked fine.  Then I changed doSomething to be `async`, like this

**TestMod.js**

```
const TestMod = {
  async doSomething() {    
  }
};

module.exports = TestMod;
```

Now I get a compilation error:

```
[1] ./src/Test.js
[1] 26:6-13 "export 'default' (imported as 'TestMod') was not found in './TestMod'
```

Why? I know how to make it work again:

**TestMod.js**

```
export const TestMod = {
  async doSomething() {    
  }
};
```

**Test.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TestMod} from './TestMod';

export default class Test extends Component {  
  render() {
    TestMod.doSomething();
    return <div>Testing</div>;
  }
}
```

But what I'd like to understand is why making a function `async` causes module.exports to break on the React side.  (By the way, it still works fine on the Node.js side).

Thanks,
Alvaro

Comment: Try it writing like this  `doSomething: async() {    }`

Comment: That doesn't compile.  This compiles but it has the same error: `doSomething: async function() { }`